# Doubts with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have an alarm that obviously calls a receiver and in the receiver it have to do some tasks and it may take some time to be done. But i heard that the onReceive() method is killed after some seconds.
I made a debug on my code and "stopped" inside the receiver and suddenly the debug stops, it happens because the onReceive() was killed?
So, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i heard that the onReceive() method is killed after some seconds

Correct. `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread. You want to get off of that thread as soon as possible. If your UI happens to be in the foreground when the broadcast is received, your UI will be frozen. Even if your UI is not in the foreground, you cannot take very long on that thread without your work being terminated.

> So, what should i do?

Delegate the work to an `IntentService`, where you start that service in `onReceive()`. If the work may take 15+ seconds, I would recommend using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, so that you can ensure the device will stay awake long enough for your work to complete. But even then, "some time to be done" should be measured in seconds, maybe minutes.

Comment: it depends on the quality of the GPS... So, i just have to change the extends from "BroadcastReceiver" to "WakefulBroadcastReceiver"?

Comment: @RafaelKehl: No, there is more to it than that. There is some example code in [the JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html), and I have a complete sample app demonstrating its use with `AlarmManager`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast

Comment: Just one thing more...
I took the example from the JavaDocs but in my IDE it says that `completeWakefulIntent(intent)` doesn't exists... You know how to solve?

Comment: @RafaelKehl: That is a static method on `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`. You can see its use in my sample app.